# When will the CheckBox.IsChecked.HasValue become false?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've used many times the following

```
if (chkBox.IsChecked.HasValue && chkBox.IsChecked.Value)
```

But why? What is the situation in which the `chkBox.IsChecked.HasValue` becomes false?

I checked by creating a checkBox and debugging it to see the `HasValue`.

Checked on constructor, Checked after Checking and Unchecking the Checkbox. But `HasValue` always found to be true.

Comment: If it is a 3-state checkbox, it can be null (.hasvalue = false).  You have to specify that it is 3state in the markup, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`chkBox.IsChecked` is a `bool?`, which means it is a nullable boolean (it can be set to `null`). The checkbox can have three values: `true`, `false` and `null`.

`HasValue` will be `false` in the case that `IsChecked` is set to `null`.

So you could bind to the `Checked` property and set the value to `null`, like in this code. `HasValue` will be `false`:

```
chkBox.IsChecked = null;
```

Also, see the documentation on the usage of [`Nullable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

`Nullable<T>` is a `struct`, and in fact it can't be `null`. It is just a trick in C#. You see it is `null`, but in fact it is a `struct` with `HasValue` set to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Checkboxes can be ThreeState - the value can be checked, unchecked, or indeterminate. If the value is indeterminate, `HasValue` returns false.

```
<CheckBox IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{x:Null}" />
```